# What if sql server exceeds its Maximum memory supported

Tags: sql-server

Situation: users experience the server as pretty slow

When starting the Task manager of the server I see that the SQLserver.exe process uses 1,5GB. Which I find bizarre as it's only an Express edition of SQL Server 2008, which has a maximum of 1GB memory.

By consequence my question:
What if sql server exceeds its Maximum memory supported ?!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://knowledge.3essentials.com/web-hosting/article/433/Evaluating-SQL-Server-2005-Express-vs-other-SQL-2005-versions.html

Found it. (impatience...)

However, memory needed to keep track of connections, locks, etc. is not counted toward the buffer pool limit. It is therefore possible that the server will use more than 1 GB in total, but it will never use more than 1GB for the buffer pool. This limitation prevents the use of Address Windowing Extensions (AWE) with SQL Server Express.

Still, that means there's over 500MB for the connections, locks, (caching) etc?
Is there a formula to know how big this files can get ?